# How to change the form action programatically according to session variable?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, forms

If i have a `form` which `action` should differ according to some session variable . How can i change the action of the form dynamically so that on client click of specific link button i could submit the form with the required action.

---

```
<form id="myform" action="I wanna to change it dynamically" method="post" > 
    <%-------------%> 
</form>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitform()
    {
      document.myform.submit();
    }

</script>
```

---

For example :

```
If session["emp"] = 1 then the action is /A.aspx

If session["emp"] = 2 then the action is /B.aspx
```

Comment: So basically you're asking how to evaluate the content of a variable, and alter the output based on that? Like an `if` and a `write` statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**

I typically place server values in hidden fields when the form loads so that I can interact with them in JavaScript:

```
function submitform()
{
    // Get URL that was set server-side for form submission
    var myHiddenObj = document.getElementById("<%= hdnServerValue.ClientID %>");

    // Get form object
    var myFormObj = document.getElementById("myform");

    // Change form action & submit
    myFormObj.action = myHiddenObj.value;
    myHiddenObj.submit();
}
```

**Option 2**

If you simply want the form action to change and require no other client-side processing, simply change the form action on the server (you'll need to add `runat="server"` to your form tag):

Markup:

```
<form id="myform" runat="server" action="" method="post" > 
    <%-------------%> 
</form>
```

C# (or your preferred server side language)

```
if(Session["emp"].ToString() == "1")
    myform.Action = "A.aspx";
else if (Session["emp"].ToString() == "2")
    myform.Action = "B.aspx";
else
    // Handle neither 1 or 2
```

Comment: and in the server side . i set the value of the hidden field with the `url` ?
Like this :

 `<asp:HiddenField ID="HDN_path" runat="server" />`
`HDN_path.Value = "/A.aspx";`

Comment: Write a server variable to the client side, to let the client post it back to evaluate it server side. Looks like a workaround to me? OP says he's basing the `action` decision based on a session variable. Why not simply put a variable in `action="<%=actionURL%>"`, and fill that variable server side based on the contents of the session variable?

Comment: @CodeCaster, the OP asked how to change the value in his JS function - I just assumed that there would be other logic in the function. If the only thing the function does is submit the form, then you're correct. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: No, i have more than form so the first one `runat ="server"` and the others without.

Comment: @just_name, I'm not sure I understand your last comment. Does one of my solutions work for you?

Comment: :) I mean that i have more than form so, i can't make all of them runat server. the first solution is okay but is my first comment is right?

Comment: You're first comment is close - except it doesn't take the session variable into account. For that, you'll need some type of logic like my second example. Here's the code to set it in the markup like your first comment: `<asp:HiddenField ID="HDN_path" runat="server" Value="A.aspx" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(condiotion1)
  form1.Attributes.Add("action", "My Action1");
else if(condiotion2)
  form1.Attributes.Add("action", "My Action2");
```