# Forms - How to POST default field values in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, post

I'm debugging an html form. I need to POST the form with the default values (some of the field values are set with JavaScript).

How can I do this programmatically in C#? I want to have an action similar to pressing the "SUBMIT" button. I'm using a WebBrowser of my own.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you make the question more clear, do you want to submit the form on some particular action?

Comment: No, I just want to submit the form with "default" values. I need to have a method that will submit the form with the default values of the fields.

Comment: Why can't you just click the submit-button?

Comment: This [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1728182.aspx/1) might help you in what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it via JavaScript in the HTML, or the browser developer tools:

```
document.getElementByTagname('form').submit();
```

Just put that in a script-tag at the bottom of your HTML, and it will post the form. Not really sure why you can't just click the "submit" button, though..

Comment: Is there a way to do this from c#?

Comment: The form is in HTML (on the client), so no.

Comment: What about "submitButton.InvokeMember("click");" as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654442/invokememberclick-webbrowser-help

Comment: did you try? I wasn't aware that it was a WebBrowser component. You should really elaborate more in your question to avoid "wrong" answers like mine. You could've mentioned that it is a browser-component in a Windows Forms application.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you want is to submit your form with the default values, though it needs to be submitted through server side i.e. c#?

You can avoid any client side processing for your form by changing certain attributes of the form tag. **[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465121/how-to-change-the-form-action-programatically-according-to-session-variable)** has some useful information for your taste.